# FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp()

Tags: firebase, vue.js

Hey I am pulling my hair out on this one - I have read several posts here but keep getting this error here is my code for init.js

```js
import firebase from "firebase/app"
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAF2VbjdWbQdsdsdk79nINQV5wdsdBn-uMy844gY7s",
    authDomain: "lcarchivewebsite.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://lcarchivewebsite.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "lcarchivewebsite",
    storageBucket: "lcarchivewebsite.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "71812947145517",
    appId: "1:718129478445517:web:0284d6bsdsdbb57384c87800c4"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
export const firestore = firebase.firestore()
export const db = firebase.database()
export const auth = firebase.auth()
export const storage = firebase.storage()
```

my component is here:

```html
<template>
<h2>hello</h2>
</template>
<script>
import storage from 'firebase'
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  },
  created(){
    var storageRef = storage.storage().ref()
    var listRef = storageRef.child('2020')
    listRef.listAll().then((response) => {console.log(response)})
  }
}
</script>
```

i have installed firebase with npm install --save
here is package.json

```js
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^7.17.1",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of problems here, the first being that you are importing from the `firebase` lib in `node_modules` where you should be importing the `storage` you exported from your `init.js` script.

Fix this with

```js
import { storage } from '@/path/to/init.js' // "@" refers to your "src" directory

// snip

var storageRef = storage.ref()
```

---

The other problem is that in order to use Firebase features like storage, you need to [import those libs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#libraries-bundle). So in `init.js`...

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/database'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/storage'
```